# Save array values based on ObjectId using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to save each document in an array as ObjectId, like that:

```
{
  materials: {
    active: "Steel",
    description: "List of materials",
    text: "Materials",
    value: ["5c44ea8163bfea185e5e2dfb", "5c44ea8163bfea185e5e2dfc"]
  }
}
```

I used an array of promises to save asynchronous each value and save the callback _id:

```
const reference = {
        materials: {
            ...project.materials,
            value: await Promise.all(project.materials.value.map(
                async (value) => {
                    const { _id } = await Material.findOneAndUpdate({ name: value.name }, value, { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }).exec();
                    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id);
                }
            ))
        },
...
}
```

There is another more simple way ?

Comment: Do you want to update all documents?

Comment: Save if is not exist, else update it. This works I just want to know if there is another more simple way to do